# ¿porque no me funciona firebase.auth()?

Tags: javascript, firebase

quiero resolver un problema en mi codigo para conectar firebase ,
pero en consola me sale  un error que dice firebase.auth() no es una funcion.

```
  <body>

<input id="email" type="email" placeholder="ingresa email">
<input id="contraseña" type="password" placeholder="ingresa contraseña">
<button type="button" name="button" onclick="registrar()">enviar</button>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<script src="app.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

aqui tambien le dejo mi codigo de javascript para poder resolver el problema , porque me sale firebase.auth() no es una funcion.

```js
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBbO0gB4q5N0QA23CwKyrrCUe3KhWF1JlI",
    authDomain: "usuarios-aff93.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://usuarios-aff93.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "usuarios-aff93",
    storageBucket: "usuarios-aff93.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "287847978495",
    appId: "1:287847978495:web:f85de989d11c17133183ca",
    measurementId: "G-LC0HV1RQ01"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
function registrar()
{
  var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
  var contraseña = document.getElementById("contraseña").value;
  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, contraseña).catch(function(error)
  {
 // Handle Errors here.
 var errorCode = error.code;
 var errorMessage = error.message;
 console.log(errorCode);
 console.log(errorMessage);
 // ...
});

}
```

ese es mi codigo javascript no se que estoy haciendo mal.

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas incluir la libreria `firebase-auth` despues de la libreria `firebase-app`

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.19.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>
```

https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#desde-la-cdn

Comment: muchisimas gracias